# How to make a @ test annotation out of data provider loop?

Tags: selenium, testing, testng, dataprovider

I have a data provider with name "name" and to the `@Test` I am passing this.
`@DataProvider(name = "TC_001")`

`@Test(dataProvider = "TC_001")`

before this `@Test` I want to run another `@Test` which need to run only once .
I have given the priority like
`@Test(priority=0)`

`@DataProvider(name = "TC_001")`

`@Test(dataProvider = "TC_001",priority=1)`
But Still the control goes to the second priority instead of first one

Is there any solution for this ?

I set the priority 1 and 2. @Test(priority=1) @DataProvider(name = "TC_001") @Test(dataProvider = "TC_001",priority=2) But Still the control goes to the second priority instead of first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a value of `priority=0` is as good as you not setting any priority at all. 
TestNG honors priorities only when they are non negative positive numbers.

To fix your problem you have two options.

1. Start with a priority of `1` and have your data driven test method use a priority of `2` (or)
2. Have your data driven test method depend on the other test method using `dependsOnMethod` attributes.

Comment: I set the priority 1 and 2.         @Test(priority=1)

@DataProvider(name = "TC_001")

@Test(dataProvider = "TC_001",priority=2) But Still the control goes to the second priority instead of first one